# Will my PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity and performance will change if I Update windows 10 to 11

Tags: sql-server, windows

I was having the issue on MSSQL DEV installing on windows 11. i followed this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size

it didnt work for me.
This is the volume info I had in windows 11.

Sample output of fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo :

```
LogicalBytesPerSector : 512 LogicalBytesPerSector : 512
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096   PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 16384
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance : 4096 PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance : 16384
FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096    FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096
Device Alignment : Aligned (0x000)  Device Alignment : Aligned (0x000)
Partition alignment on device : Aligned (0x000) Partition alignment on device : Aligned (0x000)
No Seek Penalty No Seek Penalty
Trim Supported  Trim Supported
Not DAX capable Not DAX capable
Not Thinly-Provisioned  Not Thinly-Provisioned
```

I tried doing stuff mention in Link above, But now i have downgraded to windows 10 and SQl is working fine.

My question is if i Update to windows 11 again through windows update service, will it change PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity and  PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance to like windows 11 have.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to windows 11, PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance changed to 16384 for this reason SQL Server stops working, But the link above works.